# Proving that the ideal generated by a set of polynomials is equal to the intersection of ideals containing these polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Let $F[x]$ be be the set of polynomials over a field $F$ and $f_1 , . . . , f_n \in F[x]$ be arbitrary polynomials. I'm using the following definition of an *Ideal*:

**A subset $I \subseteq F[x]$ is called an ideal if $I$ is a subspace of $F[x]$ and $fg \in I$ is true for all $f \in F[x]$ and all $g \in I$.** ($fg$ represents the usual multiplication of polynomials)

The ideal generated by the set $\{f_1 , . . . , f_n\}$ is the set $f_1F[x] + . . . + f_nF[x]$ (also a subspace of $F[x]$), where $f_iF[x]$ is defined to be the ideal $\{f_ig: g\in F[x]\}$.

Now the task/problem is to show that this genereated ideal is equal to the **intersection of all ideals of $F[x]$** *which contain $\{f_1 , . . . , f_n \}$*. I'm trying to solve this problem by inclusion of the two sets, and ive managed to show the first inclusion "generated $\subseteq$ intersection", which is fairly straightforward. I'm having troubles however with the other inclusion.

Any input is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The ideal generated by $\{ f_1, \ldots, f_n \}$ is itself one of the ideals in the intersection...

Comment: Okay, could you maybe provide a short proof of this? Somehow I can't seem to connect the dots..

Answer (score 1):

As @DanielSchepler points out, this is almost immediate, because the ideal $\langle f_1,\dots,f_n\rangle$ is an ideal containing $\{f_1,\dots,f_n\}$.  Thus you have the reverse inclusion.